# 'At least one of these fields must be filled' - Can I enforce this requirement in Django models?

Tags: django, django-models

Here's a use case:

```
class Tweet(models.Model):
url_1 = models.CharField(max_length=140)
url_2 = models.CharField(max_length=140)
url_3 = models.CharField(max_length=140)
```

I'd like the user to specify at least one URL for each Tweet instance.

I know how to enforce this condition in views.py, but I'm wondering if there's a way to configure a Django model such that the user is required to fill in at least one out of a given set of model fields before an instance can be saved. I think that solution would be cleaner.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be done at the model level, but it may be possible to add a constraint at the database level that can enforce this.

Comment: I suspected that this might be the case. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: IMHO you could enforce such a condition in a pre-save signal, or in `save()`.

Comment: @equinoxel: Only the first time. It can easily be violated by using `objects.update()` after the fact.

Answer (score 1):

Since Django 1.2 you can use clean() method of the model where you can make such check. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#django.db.models.Model.clean